# When click on button (button in cell) that particular cell should be changed?

Tags: iphone, ios

There are 1 table on uiview and I want to change the cell height when button pressed other cell's height remain same

Comment: where you are getting the button press event? In UITableViewCell subclass or view controller?

Comment: there is custom cell and button are on every cell when button pressed that particular cell height is only changed

Answer (score 1):

Pass the button press event to the view controller through delegate methods and reload the table view as follows.

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

In view controller (ie., datasource for the table view), implement [`heightForRowAtIndexPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method and return the height as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the cell height in the delegate method

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(indexPath.row == clickedRow)
    return newHeitht;

return cellHeight;
}
```

you can set some condition in button click and reload the tableview using `[tableView reloadData]`. this function will be called. return a new height for the particular cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:toReloadRows withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

then

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonClick  {

[self.tableview reloadData];

selectedRow = //do something here 

}
```

and in your UITableview Datasource

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

if(indexPath.row == selectedRow)

 return selectedRowHeight;
else
 return  defaultHeight;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

    if (isSearching && indexPath.row == selectedIndex) {
        return 110;
    }
    else {
        return rowHeight;       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a custom UITableViewCell class.
2) Populate you cell however you see fit. I use a 'hydrateWithArray' type function myself.
3) Once the data has been populated, resize and reposition elements using 'sizeToFit' functions to force labels to conform to the size of whatever you put into them. protip: by setting the frame of the label first, and setting the numer of lines to 0... when you fill the text and sizetofit, it will stretch the label vertically only and force the width to stay the same.
4) Create a seperate function (mine is called calculatedHeight) that returns a float and returns the height that you would like the cell to be in the table (based on the repositioned objects from step 3).

```
- (float)calculatedHeight {
return textLabel.frame.origin.ytextLabel.frame.size.height5;
}
```

5) In your UITableView class, you'll need to import your tableViewCell class and create a dummy cell object. You're going to use this class to calculate how tall each cell needs to be. Then in the heightOfRowAtIndex method....

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
float height;
if ( !dummyCell ) dummyCell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
[dummyCell hydrateWithTweet:[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
height = [dummyCell calculatedHeight];
if ( height == 0 ) height = 50;
return height;
}
```

This is a pretty simple example so you may need to go crazy with the error checking in your particular use, but this should at least point you in the right direction. Enjoy!